# Express layouts error - variable not defined

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using express-ejs-layouts and am seeing the following error in the console log:

```
 >> 5|          <title><%= title %></title>
title is not defined
```

I do indeed have the following element defined in my layout.ejs file:

```
    <title><%= title %></title>
```

I am populating this variable from one of my route files:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title : 'Express'
    });
});
```

Any idea what I am missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out.  There was another variable (description) that was *not* defined.  As soon as I set the 'description' variable this worked.  Seems a bit odd that the error message would be for 'title' though.

Comment: express-ejs-layouts drives me crazy with this. If anything goes wrong in the controller or view, it reports that the first variable referenced in the view or layout is undefined. Basically I can never trust the error messages I get when using express-ejs-layouts.