# EJS.JS ReferenceError: title not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, ejs

I am having an issue with a script in express. I am calling a function that renders a view, on the success of another function. In this project I am utilizing angular, node, express, and ejs as view engine. When I render the view, I unfortunately receive an ejs error of the following:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/emilywfrancis/Desktop/nodejs-angularjs-sequelizejs/views/about.ejs:5

3| <html ng-app="app">

4| <meta charset="utf-8">

5| <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

6| <% include header %>

7| <% include navbar %> 

8| <body>
  title is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
exports.verifyusers= function(req, res) {
models.user.find({
where: {
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password
}
 }).then(function(res, user) {
    if(user == "user.name") { //if user exists in database
        res.render('/about')
    };
 });
};
```

Comment: Seems like the error is actually in the `header` file. Which properly have something like this: `<%= title %>`

Comment: yes, there is -- but, I do not understand why this throws an error.

Comment: Also, the error gives an error pointing to line 5

Comment: I assume the template is compiled to JavaScript, something like: `"<title>" + title + "</title>"`. Use: `<%= (typeof title != "undefined" ? title : "") %>` and it will properly work, since the generated JavaScript is: `"<title>" + (typeof title != "undefined" ? title : "")  + "</title>"`

Comment: Yes, this works -- thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like the error is actually in the header file which proprely contains something like:

```
<%= title %>
```

I think changing changing it to the following will work:

```
<%= (typeof title != "undefined" ? title : "") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your title a value, if not already done.
If it is done, then @andlrc answer is correct, but you still want to figure out why it is throwing an error. If not, it is bad practice.

In your server define a variable names title and give it a string.
Then expose is to your view.

[In this answer you find an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433238/express-layouts-error-variable-not-defined)